# Why is there a residual connection around each attention layer followed by a layer normalization step in the in the decoder network?

Tags: neural-networks, residuals, transformers

I got the following question in a quiz, and it seems that my answer is not correct. I don't understand why:

```
Why is there a residual connection around each attention layer followed by a layer normalization step in the in the decoder network?
```

The answers:

```
To help with the interpretability. 
To speed up the training, and significantly reduce the overall processing time.
To break the symmetry in the back-prop.
To help with the parallel computing component during the training.
```

I answered "To break the symmetry in the back-prop.", but it seems that they answer is wrong!

I don't understand why my answer is wrong. Also, I don't get how any of the other answers can be correct!